# kubectl command disconnects after few minutes of idle time

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We noticed when we `exec -it` to connect into a pod, after certain idle time the connection get destroyed. Is there any option to leave the connection open longer?

I see there is an open [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/63793/files),  but wondering if there is any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. And that's why:

[Enabling TCP keepalive for console connections](https://stromasys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KBP/pages/43221121/Enabling+TCP+keepalive+for+console+connections)

> TCP keepalive is a TCP option that causes packets to be exchanged over
>   a connection even if there is no traffic to transport. It should be
>   enabled on both ends of the connection. TCP keepalive must be enabled
>   at the operating-system level **and** by the application/program
>   opening TCP connections.
>
> On Linux, edit the "/etc/sysctl.conf" file and add these lines:
>
> ```
> net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 200
> net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
> net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 50
> ```
>
> (feel free to adapt the values as you see fit). When done editing, you
>   must make the new values known to the kernel:
>
> ```
> # sysctl --load=/etc/sysctl.conf
> ```

[Custom Configuration of TCP Socket Keep-Alive Timeouts](http://coryklein.com/tcp/2015/11/25/custom-configuration-of-tcp-socket-keep-alive-timeouts.html)

> Default values for these properties is:
>
> ```
> tcp_keepalive_time = 7200 seconds
> tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
> tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75 seconds
> ```

The other possible way is to start some kind of proxy server on the client side and connect to Kubernetes apiserver through it.
I haven’t tested it myself and it could be tricky, but [here](https://ma.ttias.be/enable-keepalive-connections-in-nginx-upstream-proxy-configurations/) is an example of how to enable keepalives to backend for Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to change the timeout but one workaround might be to re-attach:

```
$ kubectl run psql --image postgres \
    --env PGHOST=<HOST> \
    --env PGUSER=<USER>  
    --env PGPASSWORD=<PWD> \
    --restart Never -- \
    bash -c 'while true; do echo -n "."; sleep 1; done'
pod/psql created

$ kubectl attach psql
Defaulting container name to psql.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/psql -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
............
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded `kubectl` from 1.11 to 1.25, solved my disconnection problem..