# How to prevent kubectl interactive shell from being closed after few minutes (increase timeout) / or terminal from dying?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I run this command:

```
kubectl run my-shell --rm -it --image alpine -- sh
```

It all works fine, but after a few minutes of inactivity the shell closes on it's own and my terminal hangs as well, so that kubectl does not remove the pod since it cannot complete.

So I am wondering, is it possible to increase the timeout before this happens, I have not found this in the documentation?

P.S. Help on preventing terminal hanging is appreciated as well, I am using ordinary windows command line.

P.P.S. This is happening in AKS, as @wolmi suggested it might be relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubectl command disconnects after few minutes of idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691104/kubectl-command-disconnects-after-few-minutes-of-idle-time)

Comment: I would rather get help with hanging terminal, it is not quite covered in the other question

Comment: Hi, can you verify in separate terminal if your pod is still running after your terminal hangs?

Comment: I have tested now and indeed the pod was running, but after I started typing in the terminal, it was stuck (no letters appeared after typing). After some seconds the terminal "unhung" itself and wrote that session was ended

Answer (score 1):

Add the `--generator` flag:

```sh
kubectl run my-shell --rm -it --image alpine --generator=run-pod/v1 -- sh
```

I tried with no problem during more than 20min idle.

By default the `run` command uses `--generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1` that is deprecated and generated a different yaml.

Comment: Do you know ho big is timeout in there?

Comment: Got the same disconnect actually, not sure how long but under 1 hour for sure

Comment: I've tested on a cluster over GKE with K8S v1.12.7, what is your version?

Comment: Client Version: v1.13.4
Server Version: v1.12.6 (this is AKS)

Comment: It seems to be AKS related if you have the chance to try it locally and/or on GKE maybe you can see the difference between these two providers.

Comment: I'll add this to the question then, did not know it's relevant :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I didn't found better solution than keeping some process running inside the container like:

```
kubectl run ala --rm -it --image alpine --generator=run-pod/v1 -- sh -c 'while sleep 120; do date; done'
```

Please refer also to the community post regarding **[TCP keepalive parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691104/kubectl-command-disconnects-after-few-minutes-of-idle-time/50705092?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C244.0324#50705092)**  - [on the server side](https://stromasys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KBP/pages/43221121/Enabling+TCP+keepalive+for+console+connections):

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 50
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

My Googling indicates this is a common issue with websocket timeouts. - No traffic on the socket in 60s (typical server-side default) and blam, it gets closed.

A simple fix is to keep traffic on the websocket. I have found this works if you run it in the interactive shell early in the session:

```
while sleep 30 ; do echo -en '\025' ; done &
```

In my experience the single '\025' char transmitted is both invisible and harmless and will not even disturb a curses-type experience on the terminal.

With that running in your shell, it should stay connected for a long time, perhaps indefinitely. Enjoy!