# Keepalive for kubectl exec

Tags: linux, bash, kubectl, keep-alive

I'm running into a peculiar issue with `kubectl exec -it ...` sessions.

They time out after 4-5 minutes depending on the cloud provider and some obscure tuning that despite my searches I could not figure out. This is a know issue, people seem to disagree wether it is due to load-balancer time-outs or kubelet ones.

Either way, none of the options on `kubectl` or`kubectl exec` offer any kind of keep-alive or timeout tuning.

I traced things with `tcpdump` and I indeed receive `RESET` packets after 4-5mins.

However I also noticed that it only happens when the session is idle. If I type any command in, the 4-5mins are reset.

So I'm looking for a way to easily send keepalive TCP/UDP packets from the kubectl session back to the calling computer, every minutes or so (and then time it out myself at my discretion).

How can I achieve that?

EDIT: another way to ask this is:
- How can I find the IP/Port back to the computer that opened the `kubectl exec` session?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50705092/11560878) solves your problem?

Comment: No it does not unfortunately

Comment: Are you using some kind of a proxy? Where is your cluster located?

Comment: I use several providers, but let's start with Azure. 
Plain normal AKS has this issue. I do not use a proxy from my computer.

Comment: Which other cloud providers do you use and have the same problem?

Comment: I do not have an access to Azure.

Comment: I have the issue on aws as well, after 19-20min

Comment: I am testing it on GCP. Will let you know how it goes. In a meantime, could you please check those parameters by executing: `sudo sysctl  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes`?

Comment: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9

Although to be honest I think a likely solution is more towards a socat proxy that does the keepalives while opening a bash for interactive use somehow.

Comment: Testing with the same keepalive values on GCP my exec has not timed out. So I was unable to reproduce your issue on GCP with various different attempts. One last question: does that happen with every pod/image or only with a specific one?

Comment: It is with every pod/image

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce your issue on GCP with different configurations and methods but I was not able to achieve the same problem.

Sadly there is no easy answer to this. Many implementations of Kubernetes rely on an SSH tunnel between the master and the nodes so that tunnel could also timeout depending on how it is configured. On GKE it has the ssh tunnel on public clusters and uses VPC peering on private clusters, but other installations could have other methods, so no easy solution.

However as a workaround you could just leave a ping running on the background to avoid being idle. That way it should not time you out anymore.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Can you describe the pinging technique you think about?

Comment: I would go for [this](https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/background.html) or one of [those](https://serverfault.com/questions/41959/how-to-send-jobs-to-background-without-stopping-them#41965)

Comment: Ah yes, pinging the caller. But how can I reach the caller?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose tcp connection for kubectl service. TCP has one keep alive mechamism. For Linux work station, default keep alive time is 7200s.

```
sysctl -a | grep keep
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
```

You can change keepalive time to 200s in /etc/sysctl.conf and 'sysclt -p ' to make it effective.

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep keep
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=200
```

**Note: This change is system level, once you change, all tcp connection will be influenced by this**

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work in a kubernetes pod, where sysctl is read-only

Comment: Actually, I found a way to modify sysctl settings with a privileged pod, and I still timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The 4-5 minutes is essentially the timeout setting of the loadbalancer that provides high availability for the cluster.

I ran into the same problem (with both `logs -f` and `exec`) and I came to the conclusion that the kubectl should send keep alive signals so that the loadbalancer does not terminate the connection because it appears idle.

So I created this feature request at the Kubernetes end for this:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94301